# How to make a program that will detect the missing string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the user to create a password, using the input() function. If the user’s password is less
than 8 characters or does not contain an exclamation mark, it prints “Your password does
not meet our requirements.”

I have this:

```
password = input("Create a password")
if len(password)<8: 
  print("Your password doesn't meet the requirements")
if("!" not in password.title()):
  print("Your password doesn't meet the requirements")
```

I used .title() because that is what I've learned so far. It isn't correct probably.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of clarity on why (a) you’ve elected to process a password with the `title()` method, and (b) why the code you included here doesn’t meet your requirements? Can you please also verify the indentation of your code in your question matches *exactly* what’s in your IDE?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check both conditions with separate if statements, indent the last two lines further, and that does exactly what you want

You can check both conditions at once, however (and there's no point in capitalizing a string to check for special characters, or length for that matter)

```
if len(password)<8 or "!" not in password:
  print("Your password doesn't meet the requirements")
```

If you want more complicated/precise passwords (only alphanumeric, special characters, etc), use regex

Comment: There is an extra parenthesis at the end of the condition. Remove that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its can help:

```
password = input("Create a password")
if len(password) < 8 or "!" not in password: 
  print("Your password doesn't meet the requirements")
else:
  #your code is here
```